# Highly precise division, multiplication, and exponentiation of large complex numbers

Tags: python, floating-point, decimal, python-3.7, complex-numbers

I am working on a project that requires highly precise division of large numbers which will sometimes be complex numbers. I need to do this in python, preferably python 3.7, but everything I have tried so far has not worked at all.

With real numbers, I can simply use the decimal module, but I found the decimal module does not work for complex numbers. In addition, when I have tried to extend the decimal module to the complex numbers, it has failed as I get inaccurate results with both large real and large complex inputs. When trying to download external modules with the functionality, it has not worked.

```
from decimal import *
def div(a,b):
    y = b.real - (b.imag*1j)
    a = a*y
    b = Decimal((b*y).real)
    return [Decimal(a.real)/b,Decimal(a.imag)/b]
```

Here is my code for using the decimal module on complex numbers, and to demonstrate what I mean (and to demonstrate this method of division works) Ill show below some inputs and outputs. The first one will be the method of working with relatively small inputs, and the 2nd will be the method very much not working with a large input.

```
>>> div(13243,23)[0]*23
Decimal('13243.00000000000000000000000')

>>> div(15**17,23)[0]*23
Decimal('98526125335693355453.21739130')
```

The result from trying with `15**17` is not only a few thousand higher than `15**17`, but it's also not a whole number. This is very incorrect. As said I need this method to be transferable to the complex numbers, and as it stands to store complex numbers in a list is a pain and not ideal. It was necessary to do so in order to use decimal on the parts though, however, it clearly hasn't worked.

I thought at first that perhaps it was a case of I just needed to set the precision higher, but even when set to 1000 it still fails.

At this point, I tried to find some modules that would allow me to do this. I found 2. `mpmath` and `gmpy`. I tried to install `gmpy` via pip, and I tried doing so on multiple versions of python and with multiple versions of `gmpy`, and each time I got an error message, normally one about a sever "actively refusing connection", as well as others saying it wasn't supported, etc.

This kind of leaves me stuck. I can't get the modules that do it for me, and when I try to do it myself it quite blatantly isn't working. Is there another module that provides this functionality out there or is there something I am particularly doing wrong with my attempts that can be fixed somehow?

Comment: very good question. I would think: numpy,scipy and gmpy2 was made to handle this.

Comment: Is there a particular functionality with numpy that does it? `numpy.float` didn't work but I am not familiar enough with the module to know if there is some other functionality that may do it. I don't have the scipy installed yet but will try to install it later. Also, just to note, I had the same difficulties with installing `gmpy2` as I did with `mpmath` and `gmpy`.

Comment: i think you should try installing `scipy` and `gmpy2`. The error you get seems to be from your network. You might be in company firewall or using a proxy. One method could be downloading the `.whl` and installing with `pip` or setting you `pip` to go through the proxy server.

Comment: oh i see. Thats odd. I was using pip but I guess a firewall or my network must be being a pain.

Comment: @Evelyn: Your `y` value here is a regular complex number, in which both real and imaginary parts have the usual `float` precision. So you've lost the precision you need long before `Decimal` enters the picture. It's perfectly feasible to write a `Decimal`-based complex class, but you'd need to do the operations in such a way that they don't go through floats. That's not hard, but it does mean avoiding things like `1j`, which has type `complex`.

Comment: I maintain `gmpy/gmpy2` and Windows support is lagging. If you let me know which version of Python you are using, I will make sure it gets support soon. Meanwhile, I would try `mpmath`. It doesn't have any external dependencies. (This assumes that pip is working....)

Comment: I am using python 3.7 @casevh